# Why TableView return only one cell?

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, dictionary

I'm parsing JSON from iTunes Store to retrieve information about musicians. While, parsing I receive such dictionary, that is printing to my console.

```
"resultCount": 50
```

Here is my method to return objects. However, the dictionary contains more than 50 elements, program return only one elements of dictionary.

```
extension SearchViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if !hasSearched {
            return 0
        }
        else if searchResults.count == 0 {
            return 1
        } else {
            return searchResults.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if searchResults.count == 0 {
            return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCellIdentifires.nothingFoundCell, for: indexPath)

        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCellIdentifires.searchResultCell, for: indexPath) as! SearchResultCell

            let searchResult = searchResults[indexPath.row]
            cell.nameLabel.text = searchResult.name

            if searchResult.artistName.isEmpty {
                cell.artistNameLabel.text = "Unknown"
            } else {
                cell.artistNameLabel.text = String(format: "%@ (%@)", searchResult.artistName, kindForDisplay(kind: searchResult.kind))
            }

            return cell
        }
    }

    func kindForDisplay(kind: String) -> String {
        switch kind {
        case "album": return "Album"
        case "audiobook": return "Audio Book"
        case "book": return "Book"
        case "ebook": return "E-Book"
        case "feature-movie": return "Movie"
        case "music-video": return "Music Video"
        case "podcast": return "Podcast"
        case "software": return "App"
        case "song": return "Song"
        case "tv-episode": return "TV Episode"
        default: return kind
        }
    }



extension SearchViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    if searchResults.count == 0 {
        return nil
    } else {
        return indexPath
    }
}

}
```

Am I mistaken in writing this method, or I should look closely on other one?

Comment: How are you initializing `searchResults`?  From the looks of your code it might be finding `searchResults.count = 0` and returning 1 in the `numberOfRows` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your search result is a dictionary, but when you call the count method on it, it does not return the value you are hoping to see for `"resultCount"`.

Instead, use the following command in your number of rows function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if !hasSearched {
        return 0
    }

    guard let count = searchResults["resultCount"], count > 0 else {
        return 1
    }

    return  count
}
```

The new return call will either give the result of your count, or a default value of 1 if nothing is present.

This was tested with a value of 0, 50 and nil and returned 1, 50 and 1 respectively.